# bash how to search for a string in all files in given directory using grep command

Tags: bash, shell

my code till now is. I am a beginner.

```
count=0
for f in $ls do
count+= grep -c "classes" $f
done
echo $count
```

Answer (score 121):

Just use

```
grep -R <stringToSearch> <dirName>
```

e.g to search "text" in current directory and  all the files inside

```
grep -R "text" .
```

If you want to get number of occurrences use `wc -l` as pipe

```
grep -R "text" . | wc -l
```

Comment: -R = recursively search sub-directories

Answer (score 14):

```
grep -rnw <Directory_path> -e "Pattern"
```

Example, if you want to find "helloWorld" in all the files of the directory `~/abc/xyz`, then run the following command-

```
grep -rnw ~/abc/xyz -e "helloWorld"
```

To search a string "HelloWorld" in the current directory, use the following command-

```
grep -rnw . -e "helloWorld"
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe find will be the BEST option for this requirement, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
find . -type f  -exec grep -i "test" {} + | wc -l
OR
find . -type f  | xargs grep -i "test" | wc -l
```

You could mention your path in place of DOT above too.

Comment: the question explicitly asks for grep

Comment: grep is there with find, find is used to make sure we are only dealing with files here.

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0
for f in *
do
if [ -f "$f" ] #check if that file is regular file
then
    count=$(($count+$(grep -c "classes" "$f")))
fi
done
echo $count
```

Comment: `grep: all: No such file or directory
grep: it: No such file or directory
grep: takes.jpg: No such file or directory
./script8: line 4: 0+: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")
0
`

Comment: all it takes.jpg is a file in my directory + the answer should be 13

Comment: seems like you can help me with this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799657/bash-adding-a-string-to-file-name

Comment: `grep: untitled folder: Is a directory
./script8: line 4: 8+: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")
8`

Comment: You must say that there are also directories in your current directory. :3 have edited answer